# About translating ～てもらおう

Tags: translation

I was translating some lines and I'm not quite sure the best way to go through this one, specifically the もらおう bit:

> 君の妄言もいい加減にして**もらおう**！

Now, I'm aware of the usage of ～てもらう but what would be the best way to bring the volitional form to English?

Keep in mind that the speaker is actively hostile to the listener, so I'm stuck between two ways of reading this: a more direct translation ("I will have you cease your inane rambling!") and one that keeps the intent but is more active ("I will put an end to your inane rambling!").

Are both versions acceptable or is only one incorrect? Or, even, are neither correct?

Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: If I may speak from the native speaker's perspective, this is much closer to imperative in nuance than to volitional.

Comment: @ 非回答者: That so? I actually thought of running it as "Cease your inane rambling" but didn't because I wasn't sure it could interpreted as imperative-esque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one can objectively translate the more subtle points of Japanese, and you should aim for something that sounds the most natural in English.

Anyway, the first one sounds better to me.

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. Taking it all into account and what 非回答者 said, I'll just do that.